# Google InApp Payment connected to web app (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, android, wordpress, woocommerce, android-pay

I am trying to integrate Google Wallet Payment or InApp payment to an Android Mobile App which is connected to a portal based on WooCommerce/Wordpress in the backend to sell keys the mobile has a in-browser which means that client won't leave the mobile app and the whole process will be done into the app itself hiding the original source/link to the client.

Is there a way to connect Google to Woocommerce to process the payments?

I found this example for iOS would it work for Android?

```
global $woocommerce;
$user = get_user_by('id',$shopId);
if ($user){
wp_set_current_user($shopId,$user->user_login);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($shopId);
    do_action('wp_login',$user->user_login);
}

if (is_user_logged_in()){
    $cart = new WC_Cart();
    $checkout = new WC_Checkout();
    if ($cart->add_to_cart($productId)){
        $orderId = $checkout->create_order(intval($shopId));



    }
    if (!empty($orderId)){
        $order = new WC_Order($orderId);
        if (!empty($order)){
            $order->update_status("completed","ios app purchase");//I HAD TO SET IT TO COMPLETE SINCE USER BOUGHT IT FROM IOS IN APP PURCHASE
        }
        //

    }
    else{
        $order = array('fail');
    }
}
else{
    $order = array();
}

return array($order);
```

Comment: This question is extremely broad and sounds like it is more of a project for a developer than a specific programming question. Can you narrow it down?

Comment: @helgatheviking thanks for the comment. I've edited and added the code to my question. However what I'm looking for is to receive payments via Google Wallet on the mobile app once completed successfully send the result to Woocommerce and then Woocommerce sends the file back to the customer.